# MaterialUI: Concise way to to define styled Components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to find a way to easily define convenience components in my app using Material-UI.

I copied an example from the [Material-UI doco for Appbar](https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/#app-bar-with-menu) and tried to introduce some React components to increase readability.

My question is about the contrast in boilerplate between the `MenuShortcutBar` function and the `MenuShortcutItem` class below.

`MenuShortcutBar` is fairly concise; but as soon as the Material-UI styling comes into it, I end up needing a lot of boilerplate.  I had to define a class, a property interface which needs to extend `WithStyles` and a constructor.

So the question: Is there a concise way to create styled React components when using Material-UI?  How can I simplify `MenuShortcutItem`?

```
import * as React from "react";
import {ReactNode, SyntheticEvent} from "react";
import {
  AppBar,
  Hidden,
  IconButton,
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  SvgIcon,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  withStyles,
  WithStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";
import {SvgIconProps} from "@material-ui/core/SvgIcon";
import {SendMailSvg} from "component/svg-icon/SendMailSvg";

export interface MuiAppBarProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {

}

class MuiAppBar extends React.Component<
  MuiAppBarProps,
  { anchorEl?: HTMLElement, }
>{

  constructor(props: MuiAppBarProps, context?: any){
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {anchorEl: undefined}
  }

  handleMenu = (event:SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: undefined });
  };

  render(){
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" color={"default"}>
        <Toolbar variant={"dense"}>
          <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit">
            <MenuIcon/>
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit">
            <SendMailSvg width={"2em"}/>
          </IconButton>
          <MenuShortcutBar>
              <MenuShortcutItem classes={this.props.classes}>
                Keywords
              </MenuShortcutItem>
              <MenuShortcutItem classes={this.props.classes}>
                Forwarded
              </MenuShortcutItem>
              <MenuShortcutItem classes={this.props.classes}>
                Rejected
              </MenuShortcutItem>
          </MenuShortcutBar>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  }
}

...

function MenuShortcutBar(props:{children: ReactNode}){
  return <Hidden smDown>
    {/* Avoid shortcuts wrapping which causes AppBar to grow in height */}
    <span style={{
      display: "flex", flexWrap: "nowrap", overflow: "hidden"
    }}>
      {props.children}
    </span>
  </Hidden>
}

interface MenuShortcutItemProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  children: React.ReactNode
}
class MenuShortcutItem extends React.Component<
  MenuShortcutItemProps,
  any
>{
  constructor(props: MenuShortcutItemProps, context?: any){
    super(props, context);
  }
  render(){
    return <IconButton color="inherit"
      className={this.props.classes.menuButton}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </IconButton>
  }
}

const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  grow: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
};
export default withStyles(styles)(MuiAppBar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some info in the [Material-UI Typescript guide](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#decorating-components) that helped me have a better attempt.

Thanks to Martin Hochel for his [Typescript pro tips](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/10-typescript-pro-tips-patterns-with-or-without-react-5799488d6680) post that put me on to using type intersection to mix `WithStyles` into the Props definition (I was hung up on trying to use `extends`).

A more concise function-style definition:

```
const MenuShortcutItem2 = withStyles(styles)((
  props:{children:ReactNode} & WithStyles<typeof styles>
) => (
  <IconButton className={props.classes.menuButton} color="inherit">
    {props.children}
  </IconButton>
));
```

And a fairly concise class-style component definition for when state is needed:

```
const ScreenContainer = withStyles(style)(class extends React.Component<
  {children:ReactNode} & WithStyles<typeof style>
>{
  state = {message: "wibble"} as {message?: string};
  render(){
    return <main className={this.props.classes.mainLayout}>
      <Paper className={this.props.classes.paper}>
        {this.props.children}
        {this.state.message}
      </Paper>
    </main>
  }
});
```

Some problems with above:

1. The duplication in repeating `withStyles(styles)` and `WithStyles<typeof styles>` is mildly annoying.
2. There's also some slight duplication there of the property names in the defintion of the state, but it's still better than the standard constructor arrangement (where you duplicate the property names anyway, but need at least three more lines of boilerplate).